# How to notify children of the layout they are being pressed?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a Row of Boxes, the main idea is I want to hightlight the currently pressed box, for example make it a different color, however I can't find a suitable out-of-the-box solution for this.

```
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
val pressed = interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()
```

This is the way I usually handle presses but I cant seem to find any way to make it work for multiple elements. And if I put the interaction source on the parent element I don't have any way to know what child is being pressed at the moment

Comment: What does not suit `Modifier.clickable` and standard 'highlight selected element'?

Comment: Didn't get your comment. What I meant is that PressInteraction.Press is responsible for notifying if the element itself was press but there is a lack of API (or I am just not aware of it) for the event of element being held on, i.e. I pressed outside the element, then moved my finger to it and hold it

Comment: Yes. It seems to be needed for MutableInteractionSource. But you have to create a MutableInteractionSource for each element.

Comment: Looks like MutableInteractionSource won't help you. It does not see events if they started outside. Modifier.scrollable and pointerInput also won't help (

Comment: You definitely should have a separate `interactionSource` for each item you wanna track, otherwise it's impossible to say which one triggered the press. If this didn't help, please provide show how you've tried

Answer (score -1):

I hope it can help

```
var currentClickIndex = remember{mutableStateOf(-1)}
val selectedColor = Color.Green
val unselectedColor = Color.Gray
Row{
 for(i in 0..5){
  
   Box(modifier = Modifier
                  .background(color = if(i == currentClickIndex) selectedColor else unselectedColor
                  .clickable{ currentIndex = i })
 }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, this code is badly formatted but I would say as far to say it's non-working since you need content or hardcapped dimensions for boxes to display at all. 
But more importantly my issue is complete different: If we would follow your example with boxes, imagine the scenario where I click on the first box and then I move my finger through all boxes without releasing or tapping again and the currently touched box should highlight.

Comment: I have achieved this effect with a lot of workarounds and overhead, once I clean it up, if I will manage to I will post the solution myself. But to me this looks like a lack of PressInteraction API

Comment: I was just giving you the idea how things can be achieved , obviously I know dimensions and all , we don't spoon feed here at stackoverflow , and In case you are handing gestures that is different thing but still the logic above will help. thankyou